# Meteor: GraphicsMagick not installing, probably a very simple issue

Tags: meteor

I'm wanting to try out the "[gm](http://aheckmann.github.io/gm/)" node package.  I've currently got node-gd installed and want to see what gm offers.

I'm using Meteor 0.9.0.1 and this is my packages.json file:

```
{
  "node-gd":"0.2.3",
  "gm"     :"1.16.0"
}
```

I ran "meteor update" .... It didn't install, so I guess I've done something wrong.

```
me@ubuntu:~/myapp$ meteor update
Refreshing package metadata. This may take a moment.
Refreshing package metadata. This may take a moment.
upgraded autoupdate from version 1.0.4 to version 1.0.5
upgraded less from version 1.0.5 to version 1.0.6
myapp: updated to Meteor 0.9.0.1.
All your package dependencies are already up to date.
```

Can anyone advise how to install this?

Answer (score 1):

I think you need `meteorhacks:npm`

```
meteor add meteorhacks:npm
meteor
```

This should trigger the installation of the npm modules. Of note may be the new notation is `Meteor.npmRequire` and no longer `Meteor.require`

Comment: I already have meteorhacks:npm installed, I thought doing meteor update would then install the gm module.  Any other ideas? :)

Comment: It installs when you run meteor, or at least it should. As in `meteor` on its own without anything else

Comment: `@ubuntu:~/npmtest$ meteor
  added npm-container at version 1.0.0
[[[[[ ~/npmtest ]]]]]

=> Started proxy.
=> Started MongoDB.     
npm-container: updating npm dependencies -- node-gd, gm...
=> Started your app.

=> App running at: http://localhost:3000/
`

Comment: I tried creating a new app and installing it from there, seemed to work - bizarre!